# Ratio of Stagnation to Normal Flow Properties in Incompressible Flows

Tags: thermodynamics, fluid-dynamics, pressure, ideal-gas, bernoulli-equation

I know in compressible flows the ratio of stagnation to normal flow variables is a function of the Mach number and usually the specific heat ratio. Does this ratio mean anything for incompressible flows? That is consider the pressure ratio $$\frac{p_t}{p}=f(Ma,\gamma)$$ which would need to be determined. In Incompressible flow the $Ma<<1$ so I'm unsure how this would affect the function. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks @Benjamin I apologize for not getting back sooner. I think the answer to my question essentially lies with the Bernoulli equation which means I need to have the conservation equations in compressible flow.